# nginx Subdomain Redirect to URL

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a server running nginx + php5-fpm with a wordpress installation.  My website is served on example.com and I would like to configure admin.example.com to point my site contributors to example.com/wp-admin. How do I configure my server{} block to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
server {
    server_name  admin.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com/wp-admin permanent;
}
```

Comment: edit: removing the completely false statement I made in this comment. This worked.

Comment: There's no point in a capture you're not using. rewrite ^ http... would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    location / {
        root   /home/kiputih0/public_html;
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

In my permalinks I've custom rules:
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%.html

And when I browse to some article it will be:

/2010/11/15/beta.html

Cheers...